# Where to put @user.skip_confirmation! in devise signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I want to skip confirmation email in signup and want to send manually. To skip I will do

`@user.skip_confirmation!`

But where to write this line?

Comment: are you using devise gem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ActiveRecord::Callbacks#before_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_create)

Write this in your **User** model

```
before_create :my_method

def my_method
 self.skip_confirmation!
end
```